# Xcode how do i know which version of the OS i'm building for?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I'm trying to figure out what version of the OS I'm building for, i.e. 6.0, 6.1, 7.1.  All the variables in the environment either point to the base version or the latest SDK version.  So if I set to build the 6.1 simulator, and my deployment target is 6.0 and the base SDK version is 7.1, this is all I see in the build environment:

```
    SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
SDK_NAME=iphonesimulator7.1
PLATFORM_VERSION_AVAILABILITY_H_FORMAT=70100
SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0`enter code here`
```

There is nothing there at all to indicate that I'm building for 6.1

So how do I figure this out?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that information from? If you look under `General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target` you should see what OS version you're building for.

Comment: i've added a script to the Build Phases of the project, which is simply "env > ~/version"

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal you can easily get the Deployment Target for your project:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

output:

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 7.1
```

Or in XCode highlight your target and look under:

```
General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your project - then the target and the general tab

[image]

Also check the deployment target for your storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the issue is, IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET will always be what is set in the General Settings.  so if i have

[image: Setting in General Settings]

and then i set it to build for 7.1 like so:

[image: 7.1]

IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET will always display as 6.0.  i'm trying to figure out that 7.1 part...